# PHP objects and arrays

Tags: php

Hi I am new to PHP and I need to  create an array and add both books to the array and than loop through the array this is where I am having trouble
if the price of a book is less than $20.00 output the book’s name and price
if the book’s title comes after the letter R in the alphabet output the book’s title.
My code so far is:

```
<?php
class Book {
  // Properties
  public $price;
  public $title;

  // Methods
  function set_price($price) {
    $this->price = $price;
  }
  function get_price() {
    return $this->price;
  }
  function set_title($title) {
    $this->title = $title;
  }
  function get_title() {
    return $this->title;
  }
}

$first_book = new Book();
$first_book->set_price('$13.95');
$first_book->set_title('Moby Dick');
echo "Price: " . $first_book->get_price();
echo "<br>";
echo "Title: " .  $first_book->get_title();
echo "<br>";
$second_book = new Book();
$second_book->set_price('$23.99');
$second_book->set_title('Wuthering Heights');
echo "Price: " . $second_book->get_price();
echo "<br>";
echo "Title: " .  $second_book->get_title();
echo "<br>";
$book = array("Moby Dick", "Wuthering Heights");
echo "Book Titles: " . $book[0] . ", "  . " and " . $book[1] . ".";

 ?>
```

Kind Regurds
Kelly

Comment: I would add a couple of extra functions... 1) isTitleCategoryR it returns true or false as reqiured.  2) Is PriceLessThanLimit($limit). Yes I know it is clumsy. :) However, is is easy to code,  understand, debug and test. :) You can 'optimize' it later. :) Example Test: If (isTitleCategoryR() && (isPriceLessThanLimit(20)) then ... else ....

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answer my question helped me out so much

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you got most of it already, for the rest I would add a function to your `Book` class to get the first character of the title, and then use the `ord` ([PHP documentation here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)) to convert it to an integer so you can check if it comes after the letter `R`.

```
<?php
// Add this to your Book class to get the first character of the title so we can check 
// if the book comes after the letter 'R'
public function get_first_char() {
    $titleArray = str_split($this->title);
    return reset($titleArray);
}

// Instantiate your books and set properties ...

// Loop over each book
foreach ($book as $bookItem) {
    $price = $bookItem->price;
    // Right now $price is a string ('$xx.xx'), we need it to be numeric
    $price = (float) substr($price, 1);
    if ($price < 20) {
        echo $bookItem->title;
        echo $bookItem->price;
    }


    // Use the ord function to convert the ascii character into an int
    if (ord(strtoupper($bookItem->get_first_char())) > ord('R')) {
        echo $bookItem->title;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your time very helpful.